# How online builder works to build applications with user settings from stub file? VB.NET

Tags: php, vb.net, eof

How online builder work , I want to make a website where user can change setting and then the online builder built the application with user setting from stub file. And then give the download link.

I found Online Builder using EOF Tutorial. Which can solve my problem

But it shows error 'WRFFVPN' is not declared. It may be inaccessible due to its protection level.
I try to solve it but failed.

Stub:

```
Dim filesplit As String = "filesplit"
Private Sub Form1_Load(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

Dim Arr() As String = Split(IO.File.ReadAllText(Application.ExecutablePath), WRFFVPN)
 Dim Message As String = Arr(1)
 MsgBox(Message)
End Sub
```

And Builder.php

```
<?php
$filesplit = "filesplit"; //Same as filesplit string in VB.NET program
$message = $_GET["message"];
$path = "DLMe.exe";
copy("MsgBox.exe", "DLMe.exe");
$infotowrite = $filesplit . $message;
file_put_contents($path, $infotowrite, FILE_APPEND);
echo 'A program that will display a messagebox with the text "' .      $infotowrite.'" is available <a href="' . $path . '">here</a> for download.';
?>
```

But the author is not online now and this program is not working properly.

Full tutorial here http://pastebin.com/aiAZSP2K

Please help to solve this problem.